# Address for PARIS, 75000 is not what I expected

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I get a strange result whenever I try a research with geocode with the address=paris,75000

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=paris,75000&sensor=false

This returns me a place in the south of France where there is a little road called Paris !!!

```
"formatted_address" : "Paris, 83470 Seillons-Source-d'Argens, France",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 43.4958460,
              "lng" : 5.8980320
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 43.49187360,
              "lng" : 5.88903480
           }
        },*
```

Anybody knows how to fix it ?
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Adding: `region=fr` to include region biasing[<sup>dev-guide-entry</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#RegionCodes) helps a little (at least the first result makes more sense and some of the strange results have been removed), but I believe the real problem is that you are submitting an incomplete address.

All of the results that are returned for this request have: `partial_match: true`, which is basically saying that the geocoder did the best it could with incomplete information in the request. Is there any way you can add more detail to this specific request?

Answer (score 1):

75000 is not a valid postal code. Use 75001 instead (1st district or "arrondissement" in french).

In France certain large cities has several postal codes.

- 750[01..20] for Paris
- 132[01..16] for Marseille

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the geocoder is confused by the code 75000. Leaving it out produces different results. I know that each arrondissement gets its own number, 75001, 75002 etc: is 75000 a valid **postal code**? 75001 produces a valid result.

The workaround is not to use that code, anyway.